# How to print from a list in order?

Tags: python

I am getting a wrong output `[[1, 3, 2, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]]`

can anyone fix it, I'm stuck here?

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    row = [[4, 6, 5, 3, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1, 1], [4, 6, 5, 3, 3], [3, 5, 4, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2, 0, 0], [1, 3, 2, 0, 0]]
    for x in row:
        diff2 = [(x[z:]) for z in range(len(row)-1)]
    print(diff2)
```

Output

```
[[4, 6, 5, 3, 3], [4, 3, 1, 1], [5, 3, 3], [2, 2], [0]]
```

Comment: In order of what? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: first list remove nothing, second list remove the first element in the second list,third list remove the first and second element in the third list, fourth list remove the first ,second and third element in the fourth list

Comment: Joe, do not assume we know, what you want to achieve. Explain expected result.

Comment: @Joe Edit your question to include exactly what it is you are trying to do in more coherent sentences please.

Comment: @Joe. I am down voting your question, because it fails explaining what you want to do. In programming, ability to clearly express what you want to create is basic pre-requisite of any successful coding.

Comment: next time i'll try to explain it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood what you want:

```
>>> print([r[i:] for i, r in enumerate(row)])
[[4, 6, 5, 3, 3], [4, 3, 1, 1], [5, 3, 3], [2, 2], [0], []]
```

or if you don't want the last list

```
>>> print([r[i:] for i, r in enumerate(row[:-1])])
[[4, 6, 5, 3, 3], [4, 3, 1, 1], [5, 3, 3], [2, 2], [0]]
```

If you want the actual elements sorted for the chopped lists:

```
>>> print([sorted(r[i:]) for i, r in enumerate(row[:-1])])
[[3, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 1, 3, 4], [3, 3, 5], [2, 2], [0]]
```

Sorted sort:

```
>>> print(sorted([sorted(r[i:]) for i, r in enumerate(row[:-1])]))
[[0], [1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks its working , i don't need it sorted because i'm implementing an algorithm and i need there index